# Application private node.js modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I have this application folder structure:

`project root
  |
  +- controllers/
  |
  +- models/
  |
  +- node_modules/
  |
  +- utils/
  |
  +- tests/
  |
  +- package.json`

I have some shared functionality in `utils` folder, which I want to use in files inside `models`, `controllers` and `tests` folders.

I want to reference `utils` module like `var utils = require('utils');`, and I want to store it in application repository.

I do not want to write things like `var utils = require('../../utils');`, it seems ugly. I don't want to place `utils` folder into `node_modules` because `node_modules` stores third-party dependencies installed by `npm install` and is not under version control, and I don't want to mix private and third-party code.

Is there any solution?

UPD: The only approach I know is to make in `node_modules` folder symbolic link to `utils` folder by some kind of install script. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. In theory, you could store your `utils` in your project tree and install it into `node_modules` during your project installation via custom install command (you know, you can provide a file path to npm to install a package)...

Comment: Or, if you are sure you are not breaking anything, simply import the `utils` in some main script, like `index.js` and export the contents into global scope. DISCLAIMER: exporting to global scope is **not** recommended unless you know what you are doing.:)

Comment: You could always use a private npm.  Reggie is awesome: https://www.npmjs.org/package/reggie.  Way easier/more useful than you might think.

Comment: Actually I don't really want to share `utils` functionality _between projects_, so private npm seems like overkill, also this probably not so convenient to modify code inside `utils`, and if I want to scale this approach I will end up with tons of 'projectX-utils' modules in private npm.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `NODE_PATH` to your environment:

```
export NODE_PATH=`pwd`
```

and it should find utils if you have an index.js in the root of the `utils` directory

Comment: This works, but seems like a hack. Also, any other developer on project will have to add this setting to his environment too.

Comment: We've been using it this way for about 2 years now, we store quite a few things in our env, so it hasn't been an issue for us

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference something by `utils` name instead of `./utils`, it **has** to be in node_modules folder.

There is nothing wrong with it, you can have a file structure like this:

```
project root
| +- controllers/
| +- models/
| +- node_modules/
|    | +- utils/
| +- tests/
| +- package.json
```

Note that you have to add `bundleDependencies: ['utils']` to your package descriptor file, otherwise it won't be packed by npm.